# how to disable 'anchor' on submit form after validation in jQuery php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a small problem, a form on submit is being validated then I am sending it but I need to disable my submit button onClick if validation is successfull here is my button code

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary " id="submitBtn"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Kişi Kayıt</button>
```

and here is my jQuery code

```
..... here is validation codes .....
submitHandler: function(form) {

$.ajax({
    url: 'plugin/clientIssues.php?tU=1',
    type: "POST",
    data: $('#userReg').serialize(),
    success: function(response) {
               alert(response); // show response from the php script.

               window.setTimeout('location.reload()', 300);
             }            
     });
    return false;
    $form.submit();
 }
});
```

Do you have any idea where I can put

```
$('#submitBtn').hide();
```

if the validation is correct and pressed on submit button ?

Comment: Your `$form.submit();` does never get executed, because you placed it after the `return` statement, which leaves the function. (Neither _should_ it be executed, since you are sending the data via AJAX.) And how do your validation and submit handling work together? Is/can validation be called independent of the submit button?

Comment: You know your submit button is just a button, so you will need to call the submit method manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your success function:

```
success: function(response) {
           alert(response); // show response from the php script.
           $('#submitBtn').hide();
           window.setTimeout('location.reload()', 300);
         }
```

Although I'd (personally) just disable the button:

```
success: function(response) {
           alert(response); // show response from the php script.
           $('#submitBtn').attr('disabled','true');
           window.setTimeout('location.reload()', 300);
         }
```

Comment: thanks that worked actually I tried the same but after I took your snippet everything seems fine :)